# Powershell Add-Content -Value with more than one parameter

Tags: powershell, parameters, quoting

Okay someone suggested that I start a new question because my original question was solved but I have another question which belongs to my problem from before.

My first problem was that I wanted to write text in a txt file using double quotes. That is solved. My next problem / question is how can I work with more than one parameter in `Add-Content -Value`?

Here is an example:

`Add-Content -Value '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Fraunhofer IIS\easyDCP Creator+\bin\easyDCP Creator+.exe" "-i C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\dcp_bearbeitet\$title\$title.txt" "-o" "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\output_dcp\$title"'`

In this case parameter $title stands for the title of the video clip I am working on and I do not know the title when I am working on it, that is why I am using this parameter. But when I am running my script, power-shell totally ignores my parameter. So I tried it again with single quotes around the parameter for example:

... `"-i C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\dcp_bearbeitet\'$title'\'$title'.txt"` ...

And then power-shell does not even perform my script. So maybe somebody knows how I can work with parameters in Add-Content -Value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two competing requirements:

- you want to substitute a variable into the command you are building so you need to use double quotes
- you want to include double quotes in the output, so you either have to escape them or use single quotes round the string.

One way is to use a here-string, i.e. @"..."@ to delimit the string instead of just using ordinary quotes:

```
$value = @"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Fraunhofer IIS\easyDCP Creator+\bin\easyDCP Creator+.exe" -i "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\dcp_bearbeitet\$title\$title.txt" -o "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\output_dcp\$title"
"@
Add-Content -Value $value
```

That should work for you. I separated it out from `Add-Content` not because it wouldn't work in-place, but because there is less scope for confusion to do one thing at a time. Also if you build the value up separately you can add a temporary `Write-Host $value` to quickly check you have the string exactly as you want it.

Another way is simply to escape the enclosed quotes:

```
$value = "`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Fraunhofer IIS\easyDCP Creator+\bin\easyDCP Creator+.exe`" -i `"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\dcp_bearbeitet\$title\$title.txt`" -o `"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\output_dcp\$title`""
Add-Content -Value $value
```

but that does get messy.

Other options would be to build up the string in small chunks, or to use a different character instead of the double quotes inside the string and then do a replace to turn them into the quotes, but either of these is messy. I would go for the "here-string" solution.

Comment: thank you for your answer, this was exactly what I needed. Case is closed and you get my answer. Never thought it would be so tricky, but in the end it worked out fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass arrays into `Add-Content`.

```
$string_array = @(
    "`n",
    "line1",
    "line2",
    "line3",
    '"line4"',
    "li`"ne`"5"
)

$string_array | Add-Content file.ext
```

---

The parameter `-Value` can also take an array directly:

```
Add-Content -path cake.txt -value @('some "stuff"',"more `"backticked`" stuff","hello world")
```